# Can Python launch Firefox with a specific profile?

Tags: python, python-2.7, firefox, firefox-marionette

I'm trying to write some automated tests for Firefox using Marionette and its Python client, but Python doesn't seem to be able to launch Python with a specified profile. This is a problem because I need two Firefox profiles for the test. I'm trying to use `subprocess.call(['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe', '-P Marionette'])` but instead it launches using the default Firefox profile (which is not that one). Can Marionette change the current Firefox profile, or can Python use command line arguments to run with a specific profile?

Comment: I've got a batch script workaround that starts both Firefox sessions `start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P Marionette -no-remote` and then the other profile as well, before starting the python script itself. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"-P Marionette"` must be two different entries in the list.
so use

```
subprocess.call([firefox_fullpath, "-p", "Marionette"])
```

"-P Marionette" are technically two arguments (applies for any OS I know of).